# How to limit rotation on a RigidBody2D?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Currently I am making a clone of the game Flappy Bird for practice. I am representing the bird as a `RigidBody2D`.

```
extends RigidBody2D

func _ready():
    pass

func _input(event):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("input_action_flap"):
        bird_flap()

func _physics_process(delta):
    print(self.rotation_degrees)
    
    self.rotation_degrees = -45
    
    print(self.rotation_degrees)
    
func bird_flap():
    var des_linear_velocity_x : float = get_linear_velocity().x
    var des_linear_velocity_y : float = -750
    var des_angular_velocity  : float = -3
    
    set_linear_velocity(Vector2(des_linear_velocity_x, des_linear_velocity_y))
    set_angular_velocity(des_angular_velocity)
```

I am playing around with ways to limit the possible rotation of the Node. However, I am running into some issues.

```
-135.234329
-45
-137.498474
-45
-139.724884
-45
-141.914169
-45
-144.066986
-45
-146.183914
-45
-148.265564
-45
-150.312515
-45
-152.325363
-45
```

The values of the rotation seem to be flickering wildly due to Godot's built-in physics engine. And when I try to use the method `clamp(...)` - I subsequently experience wild flickering of my character sprite's rotation.

```
self.rotation = clamp(self.rotation, deg2rad(-45), deg2rad(+45))
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly altering the state of a physics body often needs to be done in the `_integrate_forces` method instead of the `process` methods.
(see Note toward the top: [RigidBody2D documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html))

Here I'm creating and setting a new transform.

```
func _integrate_forces(state):
    var rotation_radians = deg2rad(rotation_degrees)
    var new_rotation = clamp(rotation_radians, -0.78, 0.78)
    var new_transform = Transform2D(new_rotation, position)
    state.transform = new_transform
```

Remember that `angular_velocity` is still being applied though, which will cause your body to "stick" to max/min rotation. You can fix this by tuning `angular_damp` in the editor or manually changing your `angular_velocity` in code whenever you hit the target `rotation_degrees`.

Comment: Do you happen to know the frequency that `_integrate_forces(...)` is called? I am weary of using it without a proper understanding of when exactly the method is run...

Comment: It runs each physics frame, which can be changed in your project settings and defaults to 60. https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html The "Physics process callback" and "Using Rigidbody2D" sections of this documentation give some piecemeal information on it. The documentation could definitely stand to be more explicit. Important to note though. Putting a physics body to sleep will stop callbacks on integrate_forces.

Comment: If I am interpreting this correctly, then `_physics_process(...)` and `_integrate_forces(...)` are more or less equal in every way (except for the aforementioned caveat regarding RigidBody2D, of course). Even when putting a physics body to sleep, both methods stop being called together. Is there even any substantial difference worth mentioning?

Comment: It's the only way to directly access the body's physics state. The process functions only give you delta between calls.

Comment: @AlanSTACK it looks like this answer lead you to solving the problem. Shouldn't you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Under the **Deactivation** dropdown, tick **Lock Rotation**

[image]